# saving dropdown selection in cookie

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am totally new to Bootstrap and angularjs world and I am stuck at this.
I have a simple select like this below

```
<div class="pull-left  margin-left-20">
        <select id="ddlPageSize" class="form-control form-ddl-adj"
                ng-model="params.settings().countSelected"
                ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in params.settings().countOptions"
                ng-change="params.count(params.settings().countSelected)"></select>
    </div>
```

In the controller, I have select values like this

```
var pageSizeList = [
                        { value: 5, text: "5" },
                        { value: 10, text: "10" },
                        { value: 25, text: "25" },
                        { value: 50, text: "50" },
                        { value: 100, text: "100" }
                      ];
```

5 is the option by default. Can some one tell me how to save user selection (say 10) in a cookie so that next time 10 should be the pagesize

Comment: does it really have to be in cookies? would you want that to get attached to all your requests? if not, use localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngCookies` module of AngularJS. You'll have to include angular-cookies.js in your code: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-cookies.min.js

Include `ngCookies` in your module declaration:

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngCookies'])
```

Then you can save a cookie as:

```
$cookies.put('someKey', 'someVal');
```

You can retrieve a cookie as:

```
$cookies.get('someKey')
```

Updated:
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xyf1bzo/

Comment: Thanks but how to I retrieve this cookie value in select? I know its basic but I am a newbie and have no idea about this

Comment: @PriyankaLopes Have a look at the jsfiddle link that I have added.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will try this and let you know

Comment: This is not working because the angular-js version is not matching with angular-cookies.js version. When I point to older version of angular-cookies.j s i get undefined get function error.

Comment: Which version of angularJs are you using?

Comment: @PriyankaLopes angular-cookies.js was changed from version 1.3. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Worked finally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ng-cookies

dropdown selection code html :

```
<div class="custom-param" ng-controller="themectrl">
          <label id="default-lang" class="label">Default Theme:</label>
            <select ng-change="themeChange(theme)" ng-model="theme" ng-options="theme.url as theme.name for theme in themes">
            </select>
          </div>
```

angularJS code :

```
var app = angular.module('themectrl', ['pascalprecht.translate','ngCookies'] );

app.controller('themeCtrl', function( $scope , $cookies ) {

      $scope.theme = 'theme1.value';

      // create the list of bootswatches
      $scope.themes = [
        { name: 'Theme 1', url: 'theme1.value' },
        { name: 'Theme 2', url: 'theme2.value' }
      ];

        // on dropdown change function
        $scope.themeChange = function($selectedTheme) {
            $cookies.put('ppcdfavtheme', $selectedTheme);
            $scope.theme = $selectedTheme;
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Persistence Using local storage to save your data if you want I leave a link with working example Good luck[AngularJS: Real Time Model Persistence Using Local Storage](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/25/angularjs-real-time-model-persistence-using-local-storage/)

Comment: @PriyankaLopes- can you explain what did not help?